# SQL Server CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,0), '') fails but CONVERT(INT, '') succeeds?

Tags: sql, sql-server, numeric-conversion

`PRINT CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,0), '')`

produces     `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

However,

`PRINT CONVERT(INT, '')`

produces     `0` without error...

Question: Is there some SQL Server flag for this or will I need to do case statements for every varchar to numeric conversion?  (aside from the obvious why?)

Comment: I don't think it's unreliable, it's just not a complete test.  It says that the value converts to one of the numeric types successfully, so I added conditions to test for at least one number, no dollar sign, no scientific notation, etc.

Comment: How do you know it's unreliable? You had to *ask*. When [shown different (and working) techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3760355/27535) with derived tables and CASE you said you don't want to rely on them. Downvote stands in case other folk read this.

Comment: `case when @a not like '%[^0-9.]%'` is very close but without isnumeric(), it would accept things like '123.45.67'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

```
declare @a varchar(20)
set @a = 'notanumber'
select case when isnumeric(@a) = 0 then 0 else convert(numeric(18,0),@a) end
```

Comment: I guess I could refactor and put all these concerns in in-line functions.  The only bad thing about case statements in a select statement is making the select statement three pages long.

Comment: The above won't work for all input strings, for example try @a='-' or @a='$'.  See the article referenced in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Empty string will convert to zero for float and int types, but not decimal. (And converts to 01 Jan 1900 for datetimes = zero). I don't know why.. it just is...

If you need decimal(18,0), use bigint instead. Or cast via float first

ISNUMERIC will accept `-` and `.` and `1.2E3` as a number, but all fail to convert to decimal.

Comment: My question needs to be better worded.  I meant to ask how to reliably test for a number in a string.  I see you didn't like the isnumeric with good reason, but I don't see how casting it to bigint or float first would determine it's a valid number without errors either.  From what I understand, casting the string to bigint would produce a incorrect zero value or fail the script.  Casting to float seems to always fail regardless.

Comment: @Dr. Zim: in that case, see these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622878/why-use-select-top-100-percent/1623240#1623240 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760355/how-can-i-query-between-numeric-data-on-a-not-numeric-field/3760397#3760397

Comment: I haven't seen a way to do it without isnumeric with the exception of `not myField like '%[^0-9]%' and LEN(myField) < 9` (but this doesn't work for decimal.)  However, doing isnumeric() and not (check for things it misses) worked for me (which I commented on in the answer) thus why I marked it.

Answer (score 2):

ISNUMERIC doesn't alway work as you might expect: in particular it returns True for some values that can't subsequently be converted to numeric.

[This article](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6423) describes the issue and suggests how to work around it with UDFs.

Answer (score -1):

Old question maybe but I ran into this when suddenly my varchar field was sometimes empty when I also had to convert 1,000.50 to 1000,50

My trick is to use:

```
PRINT CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,0), '0' + replace(replace(myvarchar,',',''),'.',','))
```

The preleading zero will be ignored during conversion unless myvarchar is empty.