# Converting empty varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL server 2008 R2 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 0.50.2500.0.

In my Stored Procedure,

I am converting varchar to numeric(18,2).

```
select convert(numeric(18,2),' ')
```

It returned 0.00 when the value was ' ', which was required.

But now, its giving error **'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.'**

Can anyone please tell me that what wrong I did ? or Which made this change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't get `convert(numeric(18,2), '')` to work

Comment: Is there anything related to SQL Server Versions ?

Comment: i tried both 2005 and 2012 and both throw errors

Answer (score 1):

Dont know why but try this it should work investigate further why it will allow you to do this way and if you find anything on this do update us.

```
SELECT CONVERT(numeric(18,2),CAST(' ' AS INT))
```

**Result**

```
(No column name)
0.00
```

I have been looking online for some explanation only found [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810073/sql-server-convertnumeric18-0-fails-but-convertint-succeeds) have a look still not very clear about this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

For,`DECLARE @VAL1 float;`

while executing this statement,

`select convert(numeric(18,2),(case when 2=1 then @VAL1 else @VAL end ));`

Sql server internally converts `@VAL` to `Float`(`datatype of @VAL1`) then compare gives you the output as zero.

```
DECLARE @VAL nvarchar(10);
DECLARE @VAL1 float;
set @VAL=' ';
set @VAL1=12.123;
select @VAL,@VAL1
select CONVERT(float,@VAL)--done by sql server internally 
select convert(numeric(18,2),(case when 2=1 then @VAL1 else @VAL end ));
```

but,for `DECLARE @VAL1 numeric(18,2)`

it actually gets error at sql server internal conversion.

```
DECLARE @VAL nvarchar(10);
DECLARE @VAL1 numeric(18,2);
set @VAL=' '; 
set @VAL1=12.123;
select @VAL,@VAL1
select CONVERT(numeric(18,2),@VAL)--at this point,sql sever unabled to convert @VAL to datatype Numeric
select convert(numeric(18,2),(case when 2=1 then @VAL1 else @VAL end ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need it to also work with non-blank values

```
Declare @myValue varchar(10)
SET @myValue = ' '

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN @myValue <> ' ' THEN 
            CONVERT(numeric(18,2), @myValue) 
        ELSE '0.00' 
    END
```

Outputs 0.00

```
Declare @myValue varchar(10)
SET @myValue = '3.2'

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN @myValue <> ' ' THEN 
            CONVERT(numeric(18,2), @myValue) 
        ELSE
```

Outputs 3.20

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/07/sql-server-convert-text-to-numbers-integer-cast-and-convert/

```
 SELECT CAST(YourVarcharCol AS INT) FROM Table
 SELECT CONVERT(INT, YourVarcharCol) FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All!!

I found the root cause. I have changed a column datatype **float** to **numeric** which related to the converted value.

Ex,

```
DECLARE @VAL nvarchar(10);
DECLARE @VAL1 float;
set @VAL=' ';
set @VAL1=12.123;
select convert(numeric(18,2),(case when 2=1 then @VAL1 else @VAL end ));
```

It Results

```
0.00
```

Changing @VAL1 datatype to numeric

```
DECLARE @VAL nvarchar(10);
DECLARE @VAL1 numeric(18,2);
set @VAL=' '; 
set @VAL1=12.123;
select convert(numeric(18,2),(case when 2=1 then @VAL1 else @VAL end ));
```

It Results the error, **'Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric'**.

Will be welcomed if anyone explain whats really happening here.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @value varchar(10)=''

select case when ISNUMERIC(@value)=1 then convert(numeric(18,2),@value) else convert(numeric(18,2),0) end
```

So if `@value` ='' result will be 0.00. also let say if value is 6 result will be 6.00

Answer (score 0):

Hi please take a look and try this

```
declare @xx as varchar(10)
set @xx = ''

select case when @xx ='' then convert(numeric(18,2),'0.00') 
       else convert(numeric(18,2),@xx) end as test
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use TRY_CAST()

Syntax:
TRY_CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )

Answer (score -1):

Use TRY_PARSE ( string_value AS data_type [ USING culture ] )
in your case :
**select TRY_PARSE(' '  as NUMERIC)**

Remarks :
Use TRY_PARSE only for converting from string to date/time and number types. For general type conversions, continue to use CAST or CONVERT. Keep in mind that there is a certain performance overhead in parsing the string value.

TRY_PARSE relies on the presence of .the .NET Framework Common Language Runtime (CLR).