# How to use order by with union all in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried the sql query given below:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A ORDER BY COLUMN_1)DUMMY_TABLE
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
```

It results in the following error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR
>   XML is also specified.

I need to use order by in union all. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_A 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
) dum
-- ORDER BY .....
```

but if you want to have all records from `Table_A` on the top of the result list, then you can add a user defined value, which you can use for ordering:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM (
    SELECT *, 1 sortby FROM TABLE_A 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT *, 2 sortby FROM TABLE_B
) dum
ORDER BY sortby
```

Comment: @JohnWoo - what does 'dum' do here?

Comment: @CIvemy `dum` is a table alias.

Comment: Doesn't work if you are using TOP.  Look at the answer provided by @Fandango68

Comment: One additional note: There's a rule that in the query SELECT * FROM X, no matter what you swap in for X, the rows of X are never guaranteed to be in any particular order. T-SQL won't let you swap in (SELECT * FROM TABLE_A ORDER BY COLUMN_1) for X because the ORDER BY clause won't accomplish anything at all. Now, you can swap in (SELECT TOP(10) * FROM TABLE_A ORDER BY COLUMN_1) for X, and if you do then you'll get the top ten rows, but they might be in the wrong order.

Answer (score 65):

You don't really need to have parenthesis. You can sort directly:

```
SELECT *, 1 AS RN FROM TABLE_A
UNION ALL 
SELECT *, 2 AS RN FROM TABLE_B
ORDER BY RN, COLUMN_1
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?  I found [Example C in the UNION doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx), but it shows that it can be done, and does not explain it.

Comment: @Trisped, `from where group having select order` it is the logical processing sequence. so ordering is applied in the end is legal here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

Comment: Worth noting that you have to have put all the columns you're ordering by within each of your SELECT clauses.

Comment: I wouldn't call this the right answer because you're selecting one extra column (RN). You don't always have the option/luxury of having arbitrary columns in your result set.

Comment: @pedrambashiri There is no need to select an extra column. I guess it's only here for demo purposes.
As HartleySan noted you must name the column(s) to sort on in both SELECT clauses. By using an alias (the RN column) you can sort even if the columns have different names in both tables.

Comment: It makes a great deal to have an extra column to make sure the return row is in order!

Answer (score 40):

Not an OP direct response, but I thought I would jimmy in here responding to the the OP's ERROR messsage, which may point you in another direction entirely!

All these answers are referring to an **overall** ORDER BY once the record set has been retrieved and you sort the lot.

What if you want to ORDER BY **each portion** of the UNION independantly, and still have them "joined" in the same SELECT?

```
SELECT pass1.* FROM 
 (SELECT TOP 1000 tblA.ID, tblA.CustomerName 
  FROM TABLE_A AS tblA ORDER BY 2) AS pass1
UNION ALL 
SELECT pass2.* FROM 
  (SELECT TOP 1000 tblB.ID, tblB.CustomerName 
   FROM TABLE_B AS tblB ORDER BY 2) AS pass2
```

Note the TOP 1000 is an arbitary number. Use a big enough number to capture all of the data you require.

Comment: Perfect.  Oracle allows you to sort anywhere... new to SQL Server... using TOP is great however I find it's functionality very lacking in more complex queries... I keep getting the dang ORDER BY error the OP mentioned... just let me ORDER the dang results lol.

Comment: You can use `TOP 100 PERCENT` clause. Using arbitrary number believing it will be always larger than number of returned records is bad practice.

Comment: @keiichi this is why TOP 100 is not a good idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622878/why-use-select-top-100-percent

Answer (score 1):

This solved my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT id,name FROM TABLE_A 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id,name FROM TABLE_B )  dum
order by dum.id , dum.name
```

where id and name columns available in tables and you can use your columns .

Comment: It's the same as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

There will be times when you need to do something like this :

Pull top 5 from table 1 based on a sort
and bottom 5 from table 2 based on another sort
and union these together.

**solution**

```
select * from (
-- top 5 records
select top 5 col1, col2, col3 
from table1 
group by col1, col2
order by col3 desc ) z 

union all

select * from (
-- bottom 5 records 
select top 5 col1, col2, col3 
from table2 
group by col1, col2
order by col3 ) z
```

this was the only way i was able to get around the error and worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A ORDER BY COLUMN_1)DUMMY_TABLE
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B 
ORDER BY 2;
```

***2 is column number here .. In Oracle SQL you can use the column number by which you want to sort the data***

Answer (score 0):

**Simply use that , no need parenthesis or anything else**

```
SELECT *, id as TABLE_A_ID FROM TABLE_A
UNION ALL 
SELECT *, id as TABLE_B_ID FROM TABLE_B
ORDER BY TABLE_A_ID, TABLE_B_ID
```

Answer (score -2):

### ORDER BY after the last UNION should apply to both datasets joined by union.

The solution shown below:

```
SELECT *,id AS sameColumn1 FROM Locations 
UNION ALL
SELECT *,id AS sameColumn2 FROM Cities
ORDER BY sameColumn1,sameColumn2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
select CONCAT(Name, '(',substr(occupation, 1, 1), ')') AS f1
from OCCUPATIONS
union
select temp.str AS f1 from 
(select count(occupation) AS counts, occupation, concat('There are a total of ' ,count(occupation) ,' ', lower(occupation),'s.') As str  from OCCUPATIONS group by occupation order by counts ASC, occupation ASC
 ) As temp
 order by f1
```