# GROUP BY clause error in a SELECT UNION ALL ORDER BY query

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, union-all

I am trying to sort a table after a union all in SQL SERVER

I have read in several places (here for example: [How to use order by with union all in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470191/how-to-use-order-by-with-union-all-in-sql)) that I need to write :

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
        (
            SELECT * FROM TABLE_A 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
        ) dum
-- ORDER BY .....
```

However, I keep getting an error saying :

```
Column 'dum.var' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

while I do not have any GROUP BY query ...

can someone explain this to me ?

Comment: What is the table structure for `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`?  Maybe the union itself has a problem.

Comment: No they have the same structure, i.e. four variables (and dum.var is one of them). In fact, when I omit the 'order by' and run only what I have in the parenthesis, it works well ...

Comment: Is this the exact query you are using? Or do you maybe have some MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG or whatever in your query?

Comment: Without `ORDER BY dum.var` it works?

Comment: Oh wait ... in fact in the 'order by' I use a sum ... when deleting this sum this works well. Thanks Tyron78 !!!

Comment: expand *  to column list first

Comment: that's why you require a group by... could you post the complete query?

Comment: Any chance you can show us your *actual* code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(
  ID INT
  ,Val INT
);

DECLARE @t2 TABLE(
  ID INT
  ,Val INT
);


INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30);
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES (1, 40), (2, 50), (3, 60);

 SELECT *
 FROM (
   SELECT x.ID, SUM(x.Val) SumVal
   FROM (
     SELECT ID,
            Val
       FROM @t1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ID,
            Val
       FROM @t2
   ) x
   GROUP BY x.ID
) y
ORDER BY SumVal
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tyron78 in the comments above, I spotted the mistake.

The actual query was :

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT
        *
FROM
#TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT
        *
FROM
#TABLE2
) AS Z
ORDER BY sum([Units]) DESC, [Distance], [ID], [Product]
```

The problem is in the sum() since I had already summed before in both table1 and table2. 
So the good query is the following :

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT
        *
FROM
#TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT
        *
FROM
#TABLE2
) AS Z
ORDER BY [Units] DESC, [Distance], [ID], [Product]
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide the column name on which you want to sort the resultset.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT * FROM TABLE_A 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
    ) dum
order by <column_name> [asc|desc]
```

The  must be same in both the tables.