# TSQL Percent keyword usage looks incorrect

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've never heard of `PERCENT` but according tgo http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx the `PERCENT` can be used with `TOP` to return a percentage of the records.

I am working on a function with this in it:

```
SELECT top 100 percent
```

Am I right in thinking this is exactly the same as

```
SELECT
```

Comment: Very brief answer: **Yes**, you're correct

Comment: Yes, doesn't do anything. It's often used as a hack to put in an order by where there shouldn't be one (e.g. a view).

Comment: Thanks, Ill remove this code then as its unnecessary

Comment: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified. -- Looks like you were right bridge

Comment: Related/Duplicate(?): [Why use Select Top 100 Percent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622878/why-use-select-top-100-percent)

Comment: I have heard of it used to force a CTE to materialize but only a comment.

Comment: @Bridge, `top 100 percent` doesn't do that any more in later versions of SQL server.... you have to use `TOP 999999999999` to achieve that instead...

Comment: Don't like to contradict you @Ben, but `top 100 percent` works in every version of SQL server I've used (from 6.5 through to SQL Azure).

Comment: @dav1dsm1th, it happened to me, I don't recall what the issue was exactly. Either a view or subquery or inline function? Something didn't work with top 100 percent but changing it to top 9999999999999 did... Just putting it out there.