# Why alias in SQL is not remember a subquery as a new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `SALE` with 2 columns `ID` and `Sales`.

I have code like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ID, Sales
FROM SALE
WHERE ProductID = 'IDN001'
ORDER BY Sales DESC;
```

And the result is here:

[image: 1st table]

But if I put all the code above inside the `SELECT * FROM`, it shows me the original TABLE (before ordering):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ID, Sales
     FROM SALE
     WHERE ProductID = 'IDN001'
     ORDER BY Sales DESC) AS NewQuery;
```

The new result is here:

[image: 2nd table]

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please fix your use of ALL CAPS in your title, people think you are SHOUTING at them.

Comment: The only place an ORDER BY guarantees order of displayed results is on the outer query. TOP 100 PERCENT ... ORDER BY is [completely ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622964/73226) by the optimiser in derived tables, views etc.

Comment: You need to apply the required ordering to the outer-most query; With no ordering criteria, ordering is not guaranteed exactly like it isn't when selecting from any other table.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of a subquery does not "stick" in a SQL Server query.  You need to add an explicit `ORDER BY` clause to the outer query to get the sorting behavior you want:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ID, Sales
    FROM SALE
    WHERE ProductID = 'IDN001'
    ORDER BY Sales DESC
) AS NewQuery
ORDER BY Sales DESC;
```

Comment: Might as well remove the `TOP` and `ORDER BY` from the derived table too; it'll likely be ignored by the data engine.

Comment: Can you show me the way? Thank you.

Comment: @ĐồngPhúcThiênQuốc the way to do what?

Comment: @Larnu Just realized it is top 100%...but in general removing `TOP` and `ORDER BY` would alter the result set.

Comment: If it wasn't a `TOP 100 PERCENT` yes it would change the results, @TimBiegeleisen .